# What is the difference between ruby-doc and apidock?

Tags: ruby, documentation

When I google for methods/classes in Ruby, I always get results from both sites (ruby-doc.org and apidock.com). Is one them considered the official docs? I find ruby-docs to be cleaner and easier to follow but sometimes I run across missing methods which apidock has.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**ruby-doc** is pulled straight from the ruby source code using RDoc. So if some method hasn't documentation in sources, you don't find info about it in ruby-doc.

**APIdock** is Ruby, Rails and RSpec documentation with users notes. They also get the most info from source code, but also write more details, cross references, etc. And they have very useful comments. Unfortunately, it does not develop the last several years.